# Checking quantities for future dates and returning shorts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Inventory and Orders in SQL Server.

Say Inventory reflects the current and future inventory for all orders placed.

**Inventory**

```
Item       Quantity
Shoes      100 
Coats      200
Socks      -300
```

In this case, the company is short 300 socks based on the table.

**Orders** reflects both items we buy from manufacturers and items we sell.

```
Item      Quantity      Ship_ArrivalDate      Buy_Sell
Shoes     300           10/27/2016            Sell
Socks     500           10/27/2016            Buy
Socks     500           10/29/2016            Sell
Shoes     800           10/30/2016            Buy
```

So if today is 10/24/2016, I actually have 0 shoes today. I have 200 socks on 10/27/2016 and then be short 300 socks on 10/29/2016 because **Inventory** reflects all future transactions. And after the 300 sell and 800 buy of shoes, I have 100 in inventory. But that means I will be short on 10/27/2016 for shoes.

I want to build a table that reflects all future dates and checks for days that I am going to be short.

So the table would end up looking like:

**Output**

```
Date         Item        Quantity_Short
10/27/2016   Shoes       -400
10/29/2016   Socks       -300
```

I am confused on how to check for each date and really don't know where to start. I understand how to check for 1 date in isolation, but how do you essentially "loop" through all future dates and save the dates and quantities into an output table?

Maybe writing a function that takes in a date and does the math then use apply?

Any starting advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your ms sql version?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
select date, item,
       sum(case when date > getdate() and buy_sell = 'sell' then -Quantity
                else Quantity
           End) as SumQuantity
from YourTable
group by date, item
```

Comment: @jarlh Thank you again for the solution. I implemented this a bit back, but I have the case where the only Dates that show in the output are ones that had ship_arrivalDates associated with them. Is there a good way to show all dates within a range? So say I want from 10/27 to 10/30 inclusive, even if a Buy or Sell wasa not executed.

Comment: You can use dates > 10/27 and <=10/30(with end time) in case. Not understood fully your question though. I am not a big fan of using date between startdate and enddate there are difficuties in that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify the question, sorry my example isn't ideal for this add-in, but say I want my output table to return quantities on 10/27,10/28, 10/29, 10/30 regardless of if they are short inventory or not. But I only have changes in inventory, say for shoes, on 10/27 and ,10/30 in the Orders table. How would I return all inventory levels on 10/27, 10/28, 10/29, 10/30? Does that clarify?